# Passing ID as correct variable type in GraphQL Mutate function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

I'm trying to edit an item using GraphQL by passing in arguments using this.props.mutate. I'm getting following error... **Error: GraphQL error: Variable $id of required type ID! was not provided.** Hence, the problem lies in me passing the wrong ID type to the mutate function. Anyone know how to pass the ID type as the correct type to the mutate function? or can I cast the ID type from string to the correct type to pass as variable to the mutate function? Thank you

i'm using local component state to hold the values to prefill a form in case you are wondering why I am using local state

```
import UPDATE_CHAT_MUTATIONS from '../graphql/mutations/updateChat';

class EditChat extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: '',
    id: ''
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._onEditLoad()
  }

  _onEditLoad = () => {
    const chat = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    this.setState({ text: chat.text, id: chat._id })
  }

  _onChangeText = text => this.setState({ text });

  _onEditPress = async () => {
    const { id, text } = this.state;
    await this.props.mutate({
      variables: {
        _id: id,
        text
      }
    });

    Keyboard.dismiss();
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

i managed to get it to work! I made an error on the graphql mutations on the client side. Below is the code that works!! Hope this will help those who face the same issue. Cheers

```
import { gql } from 'react-apollo';

export default gql`
  mutation updateChat($_id: ID!, $text: String!) {
    updateChat(_id: $_id, text: $text) {
      text
      _id
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```